# Music similar to american woman

Tags: music-video, similar-artists

I'm making a film and I need to use background music which has a similar effect on the listener as "American Woman".

Basically the music should be energetic and should sound stud-like. If you don't get what I mean, watch this video of Kevin Spacey singing to American Woman:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNA77Qzy3uM. Don't he look studly?

Now I can't use the same track because I don't have the money to spend on the copyrights. So I am looking for free tracks licensed under the creative commons. I am searching the hell outta freemusicarchives.org but there are so many tracks that I am pulling my hair out.

If you guys have come across similar music and that is free to use please let me know.

If this question is not suitable for this forum then please suggest the website where I can ask this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because recommendations of music for a specific situation have been classified here as *not-of-general-interest.*  If you want something in the same genre rather than the same mood, you might edit the question to reflect that --genre questions are generally considered on topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using something like YouTubes free music which allows you to download the song directly.

https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music

Then through the filter use rock and whatever mood.
By selecting just rock, the first song came up sounded similar, just a little slower than American Woman.

It is called: **Sea of Sand | 2:18 | by Ethan Meixsell | genre: Rock  | mood: Dramatic**

After playing with it more.. seems like Genre: Rock > Mood: Dramatic sounds like the good choice.